# ListView. Getting itemId when click on imageView

Tags: android, listview

In my ListView each item consists of ImageView and TextView.
I want when I click on image - get itemid(and then show image in dialog).

How to catch click on ImageView and get Id of ListItem?

[image]

```
ImageView image;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.content_friends);

            contactsList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            contactsList.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

            image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_a);
            image.setOnClickListener(imListener);

        }

        OnItemClickListener clickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long itemId) {            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "listItem " + itemId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };

        OnClickListener imListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image of listItem ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        };
```

Comment: You need to accept answers that worked for you so that next time you ask questions - people don't hesitate to post answers!

Comment: do u have any idea how to get id of showing element in list, without click?

Comment: you will found the answer in the link bellow.
try it:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14939376/1263588

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need two `Listeners`.

But, if you still insist, you have the position of the item clicked right in your code -  the `arg2` parameter of your `onItemClick()` method gives you the position of the item. If you have all images ids stored in an `ArrayList`, you could retrieve the image that was clicked using `imageArray[position]`.

Here are some pointers:

[Custom List Row](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

[Handling onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)