# onClick listener to a ListView Image - Android

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` with an image over the right hand side. and I wanted to perform a `onClick` listener event by clicking the image on the `ListView`. Please see the image for reference.

[image]

I know basic `OnClick` listener Implementations, but this seems to be a little tricky to me :P

Forgot to mention, by clicking the actual `ListView` will shootup a new activity, so I need to maintain both the schemas.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            eventsData.remove(id);
            cursor.requery(); 
        }

    });
```

The code above perform a deletion by clicking on any list element `eventsData.remove(id);` is a database helper for executing this task. like I said now I need a method to perform this same process juts by clicking the image, not the entire list element, I want the list element to do some other action later on.

I hope now I'm clear a bit.

---

**The Solution:**

*If anybody come across the same sort of situation then here is the complete code for the adapter.*

```
 class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 CustomAdapter() {
  super(Activity.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
  View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  deleteImg=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

  deleteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);      
  deleteImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      String s = items[position];
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
});

  return(row);
}
```

}

I know the coding is a bit crappy so bear with me, I just want to show the actual process that's it.

It's working for me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do it In your `Adapter` *not in `Activity`.*

```
yourImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // things you want to do 
    }
});
```

Comment: How do i determine the current state of the list element?? any pointer or identifier??

Comment: what do you mean by "current state"?

Answer (score 3):

> Create one interface for communicating from adapter to activity

```
public interface ListenerActivity        
{    
public void Remove();    
}
```

In Your Adapter Class:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

ListenerActivity listener;

CustomAdapter(YourActivity obj) {
  super(Activity.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items);

  listener=obj;
}
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
ImageId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listener.Remove();
    }
});
}
```

In Your Activity:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements ListenerActivity
{
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
 @Override
    public void Remove() {

//Do your remove functionality here
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the last answer and reering to this answer, I added some code to refresh the view after deleting an item or others actions:

```
//in your adapter you have to get list of items:

 public CartListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<CartItemModel> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items= items;
}

//after that you have to set a listner on the imageView like this:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   holder.imageViewDelete.setOnClickListener(new imageViewClickListener(position));
   // some other lines code ...
   // here we get the item to remove
    rowItem= getItem(position);
    }

//and here the definition of the listner:

private class imageViewClickListene implements OnClickListener {
   int position;
    public imageViewClickListene( int pos)
        {
            this.position = pos;
        }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    // here we  remove the selected item    
        items.remove(rowItem);
            // here we refresh the adapter
        CartListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

It works for me, enjoy !!