# How get item ID from ListFragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

In a `Class` that `extend` from `ListFragment` I am using from `onListItemClick` :

```
public class Setting_Fragment extends ListFragment{
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
         if (position == 0) {
               ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_message);
               image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("log", "here");
                 }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get `ImageView` and change the image but I can't .

I can't see `Log.i("log", "here");` .

Notice : I am using from `appcompat_v7` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715201/onclick-listener-to-a-listview-image-android

Comment: maybe you must look for onviewclicklistener or some other listener on image.Try with the alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong argument, which may be your issue.

`Position` is the position in the list that is showing. ListViews only display as many entries as is needed to fill the screen -  the ones above and below the screen aren't rendered until you scroll to them and move them onto the screen. `Position` has to do with what is being shown. `id` has to do with the actual individual id of the row, regardless of which rows are being rendered.

EDIT:

In face, the way you're doing this is all screwed up. You're only setting the `onClickListener` when the row is clicked...which makes no sense. Here is what you do.

Go into the XML for the row. In the XML for your `ImageView`, add this line:

```
android:onClick="testPrint"
```

Then in your activity, created a method at the bottom that looks like this:

```
public void testPrint(View view) {
    Log.i("log", "here");
}
```

This will print the log when you click the ImageView.

Comment: @A.A Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830505/create-a-listview-with-selectable-rows-change-background-color-of-listview-rows I put some examples of how to do this sort of thing in there.